# Maintaining the order by in union of two ordered by queries

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to run the below query but looks like I am doing something wrong.

(Just modified the sample query for clear understanding)

```
 SELECT   name,total,rate 
 FROM     business b
 WHERE rate > 100
 ORDER BY total DESC

 UNION 

 SELECT   name,total,rate 
 FROM     business b
 WHERE  rate <= 100
 ORDER BY rate ASC
```

Now I want to union of these two queries and in the resultant output in first row the output should come from first query and then output from second query in the same sorted order however the single actual query was giving.

Let me know if it is still unclear. I will try to explain in some more deep level.

Comment: What happens when you remove `ORDER BY Outer.SORTCOL;`

Comment: It will still not work if I  remove the last line.

Comment: Is there UNION between these selects?

Comment: Yes... i want to union the result set of both the queries. We can avoid it if we can find some other approach to join the result set of both the queries.

Comment: Side note: you can just use `UNION ALL` for this query, given that `rate` won't be the same in both sides (and thus there can't be duplicate sets).  This _may_ 'appear' to solve your sorting problem, but this is **not** a guarantee that your desired ordering will be returned.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select name,total,rate
  from (
        SELECT name,total,rate, row_number() over(order by total desc) rn, 1 ord
        FROM     business b
        WHERE rate > 100

        UNION 

        SELECT   name,total,rate, row_number() over(ORDER BY rate ASC) rn, 2 ord
        FROM     business b
        WHERE  rate <= 100
       )
 order by ord, rn
```

Comment: Thanks @zaratustra for your reply. The problem is that the above query is simplified version of my query. The problem in which I am looking is something like I want to preserve the sorting order of first query so I am afraid your approach will actually help me...

Comment: I modified the question with actual queries.

Answer (score 1):

It's really simple: Use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`.

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT   name,total,rate 
FROM     business b
WHERE rate > 100
ORDER BY total DESC) x
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT   name,total,rate 
FROM     business b
WHERE  rate <= 100
ORDER BY rate ASC) y
```

UNION ALL preserves order as coded.

UNION removes duplicates and does not guarantee order. Most databases actually sort the output (to make duplicate detection easier).

Comment: You can't have the `order by`  directly in the branch ([see restrictions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17118/queries004.htm#SQLRF52343)); you could [make each branch a subquery](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/36267), more like the OP's original query. But the order still isn't guaranteed. Even if it usually appears to work it might not always; and I *think* it'll break if this is run in parallel.

Comment: @alex has a point - try that modification to ordered sub queries.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Try conditional OR clause as [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/260b2/1). This will also avoid unions.

```
SELECT NAME, TOTAL, RATE FROM BUSINESS B
ORDER BY
CASE
    WHEN rate > 100 THEN total 
    WHEN rate <= 100 THEN rate 
END
```

---

Instead of using multiple layers of select query, Just include an additional field called TAB_ID in your select query and sort using that field as below:

```
SELECT CHAR1 FROM
(
        SELECT 'd' AS char1 , 2 AS sortcol, '1' AS TAB_ID  FROM   dual 
        UNION 
        SELECT 'c' AS char1 , 1 AS sortcol, '1' AS TAB_ID  FROM   dual
        UNION
        SELECT 'a' AS char1 , 1 AS sortcol, '2' AS TAB_ID  FROM   dual 
        UNION 
        SELECT 'b' AS char1 , 2 AS sortcol, '2' AS TAB_ID  FROM   dual
) ORDER BY TAB_ID, SORTCOL;
```

Check the result out from [Working SQL Fiddle Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/36264)

---

To correct your original query and avoid the missing paranthesis error, use below query, but it does not seem to provide the right output:

```
select * from
(
    SELECT * FROM 
    (
         SELECT 'd' AS char1 , 2 AS sortcol  FROM   dual 
         UNION 
         SELECT 'c' AS char1 , 1 AS sortcol  FROM   dual
    ) Inner1
      ORDER BY Inner1.sortcol
)
    UNION 
select * from
(
    SELECT * FROM 
    (
        SELECT 'a' AS char1 , 1 AS sortcol  FROM   dual 
        UNION 
        SELECT 'b' AS char1 , 2 AS sortcol  FROM   dual
    ) Inner2
    ORDER BY Inner2.sortcol
)   ;
```

Comment: Hey Nishanthi... similar approach was suggested by zaratustra but it different from what I am looking. I modified the question due to same reason.

Answer (score 0):

Add a branch flag in each of the inner branches, and sort by that first:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
  SELECT * FROM 
  (
    SELECT 'd' AS char1 , 2 AS sortcol, 1 AS branch FROM dual 
    UNION 
    SELECT 'c' AS char1 , 1 AS sortcol, 1 AS branch FROM dual
    ORDER BY sortcol
  ) Inner1
  UNION 
  SELECT * FROM 
  (
    SELECT 'a' AS char1 , 1 AS sortcol, 2 as branch FROM dual 
    UNION 
    SELECT 'b' AS char1 , 2 AS sortcol, 2 as branch FROM dual
    ORDER BY sortcol
  ) Inner2
) Outer
ORDER BY Outer.branch, Outer.SORTCOL;

CHAR1    SORTCOL     BRANCH
----- ---------- ----------
c              1          1 
d              2          1 
a              1          2 
b              2          2
```

Obviously you can replace `*` in the outer query to only get the columns you want in the result set, excluding both `branch` and `sortcol`.

[SQL Fiddle with both queries for comparison](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/36266).

Comment: Thanks Alex for your reply. Actually that was simplified query for my actual query. you removed the order by from inner query which was mandatory field in my query. Please have a look into question area again. I have modified the sample query for more understanding. Again Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @anilonwebs - where you had the `order by` was illegal - the code you posted originally wouldn't run. You can put an `order by` inside the inner blocks but it's redundant. I'll add that back just for the sake of it.

Comment: Yes you are right. That code was not working. But As I posted modified query, I can't remove the order by from inner query.

Comment: @anilonwebs - that's fine, and I already put it back into my answer, in the right place *8-)

Comment: @anilonwebs - why is the inner `ORDER BY` required?  Nothing you've shown so far would require sorting individually...