# how to combine output of 3 cursors and insert into a table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am having 3 sys_refcursor for 3 different query inside a same loop.
I want to combine the o/p of these 3 cursor and insert into a table. 
I am using the below code.here "l_ssc" and "l_nwo" are records.

```
SELECT shipper_short_code bulk collect
INTO l_ssc
FROM prepayment_ssc
ORDER BY shipper_short_code;
SELECT DISTINCT pmd_client_owner_nwo bulk collect
INTO l_nwo
FROM pp_meter_data ORDER pmd_client_owner_nwo;
FOR i IN 1.. l_ssc.count
LOOP
  FOR j IN 1.. l_nwo.count
  LOOP
    l_query_a70 := 'select * from USER_PAYS_SI_A70     where shipper_short_code =''' || l_ssc(i).ssc ||'''     and NWO_SHORT_CODE =''' ||l_nwo(j).nwo ||'''''';
    l_query_O35 := 'select * from USER_PAYS_SI_O35     where NWO_SHORT_CODE=''' || l_nwo(j).nwo ||'';
    l_query_R21 := 'select * from user_pays_si     where SHIPPER_SHORT_CODE =''' || l_ssc(i).ssc ||'''     and CLIENT_OWNER=''' || l_nwo(j).nwo ||'';
    OPEN o_cursor1 FOR l_query_a70;
    OPEN o_cursor2 FOR l_query_035;
    OPEN o_cursor3 FOR l_query_r21;
  END LOOP;
END LOOP;
/
```

Comment: Combine, you mean like a `UNION ALL` or `JOIN` ? But I think, you should also consider revisiting your approach..

Comment: I don't understand why you would use dynamic SQL here.  If you want to combine the results, are you sure that you don't want to `UNION` together the three queries rather than opening three separate cursors?  Of course, that would bring up the issue of why you have three tables with seemingly very similar definitions and very similar contents rather than having a single table possibly with an additional "type" column for the `A70` and `O35` codes.

Comment: i can't use union here . i want the data in the same way the loop is executing.By doing union it will my order of result

Comment: Why does the order matter if you're inserting? Data has no inherent order within a table. Why not insert directly from the a single unioned select, or the three individual selects - why use cursors at all, or indeed any PL/SQL? (You can [maintain the order when unioning](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26295924/266304) but I don't see how it's necessary here).

Comment: actually i want to export the data in the same way as the loop will work

Comment: _"i want the data in the same way the loop is executing"_ _"i want to export the data in the same way as the loop"_ Are you trying to walk along your 3 result sets in parallel? Maybe I missed some important point in the conversation, but you have to remember that, without a proper `ORDER BY` clause, you *must* assume the result of a select as *unordered* (well, *unpredictably ordered* if you prefer). If you absolutely need to "match" the records of the three tables together, you should definitely use a `JOIN`.

Answer (score 2):

You will run 3 queries per iteration of the loops, and this is nested inside two loops. So you will run 3 * l_ssc.count * l_nwo.count queries.

A basic principle in writing good plsql is to let the database do the processing for you.

Finding another way to write the queries into one and letting the database do the work of the loops will create a better solution.

I don’t have your tables but a rough stab at the query could be:

```
select * from (
    select upsa.* 
    from USER_PAYS_SI_A70 upsa 
    where upsa.shipper_short_code in (SELECT shipper_short_code FROM prepayment_ssc)     
    and upsa.NWO_SHORT_CODE in (SELECT DISTINCT pmd_client_owner_nwo FROM pp_meter_data)
    union all
    select upso.* 
    from USER_PAYS_SI_O35 upso 
    where upso.NWO_SHORT_CODE in (SELECT DISTINCT pmd_client_owner_nwo FROM pp_meter_data)
    union all
    select ups.* 
    from user_pays_si ups 
    where ups.SHIPPER_SHORT_CODE in (SELECT shipper_short_code FROM prepayment_ssc)      
    and ups.CLIENT_OWNER in (SELECT DISTINCT pmd_client_owner_nwo FROM pp_meter_data)
) so_far
order by so_far.SHIPPER_SHORT_CODE, so_far.NWO_SHORT_CODE
```

This won’t work but with some experimentation I am sure you can build a single query which gets the required results.

Comment: Using subquery factoring, or common table expressions (CTEs), would avoid the repeated subqueries. Each union branch can join to the CTEs (defined in a `with` clause) and those tables will only be hit once.